# How do you run a for loop in a list of lists to work with datetime?

Tags: python, list, loops, datetime

I have a list of lists:

```
[['2020', '05', '20', '22', '24', '16.7929'],
 ['2020', '05', '29', '05', '50', '12.4465'],
 ['2020', '05', '29', '06', '44', '34.1706']]
```

I want to access each element so that I can this function:

```
for x in list:
   for a, b, c, d, e, f in x:
       dt.datetime(int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d), int(e), round(float(f)).timestamp()
```

However, being a list of list of strings, it only unpacked the first element of each list (2020) and broke it apart into individual characters. However, I also learned that you cannot iterate through a list of integers like this at all. How do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's some confusion regarding what unpacking like `for a, b, c, d, e, f in x:` does.

When you write `for a, b, c, d, e, f in x:`, this is interpreted as: *for each element in `x`, unpack into the tuple `(a, b, c, d, e, f)`*.

This is why your Python interpreter will try to break `"2020"` into `(a, b, c, d, e, f)`.

What you need is: *for each element in `list`, unpack into the tuple `(a, b, c, d, e, f)`*, which translates to:

```py
for a, b, c, d, e, f in list:
    dt.datetime(int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d), int(e), int(f)).timestamp()
```

Also, as others have mentioned you have some more problems with the code.

Comment: I changed the example slightly so that there's a seconds value if you want to change your code

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in list:
  dt.datetime(int(x[0]), int(x[1]), int(x[2]), int(x[3]), round(float(x[4])), int(x[5])).timestamp()
```

Comment: I changed my example slightly so that the last item is valid if you want to change your answer

Answer (score 1):

Unpack the lists as you iterate over them, no need to iterate over them first before unpacking them

```
for a, b, c, d, e, f in list:
    dt.datetime(int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d), int(e), int(f)).timestamp()
```

You are missing seconds from your lists though and the conversion to datetime will not work

Comment: thank you, I messed up on cleaning the data I removed the period in the last element that's why it has so many characters. Not sure if I should change it because someone already answered

Comment: @python_user True, was focusing on iteration and tuple unpacking. Introducing `map` may just add to the confusion :)

Comment: that is fair enough :)

Comment: I changed the example slightly so that there's a seconds value if you want to change your code

Comment: @ACan you should separate seconds and milliseconds into individual elements. You can't pass floats to datetime and parsing them out will just make your code more complicated